# How can I make a specific bookmark from Desktop start in another browser but the standard one?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

For specific url's I'm using Chromium browser. My default browser is Firefox and should remain so.

But a few URL's I'd like to directly start in Chromium. How do I do that? I'm also using a Dock software, so this might be a bit different. Here's how it looks:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeuIf.jpg

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/306176/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-the-non-default-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each link to a website you want to open in chromium:

1. Create a Windows Shortcut to the Chromium Executable
2. After the program chromium.exe add the link in quotes

   `c:\program files (x86)\chromium\chromium.exe "http://devdocs.io/"`

Comment: Omg...I'm just stupid sometimes...Time to hit the hay I guess.

Comment: Sometimes we're blind to the simplest solutions.  I would not have learned about devdocs, and it's good to post simple questions because there are others out there who will need the help.  I manage IT for a medium sized firm, and trust me this ain't anywhere near a dumb question.